# How can I execute JavaScript after loading a part of the page using AJAX

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

How can I execute the JavaScript in the header file of a file after loading a certain part of it using jQuery load a certain part of the page with this code `$("#code_block").load('newexpenses.php #deposit_table');`. e.g. below is the part of the code that was loaded:

```
<table id=""><td><span class="f3">Cheque No</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="ch_no" id="ch_no" value=""></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="save_expenses" id="save_expenses" value="Save Expenses"></td>
```

The file newexpenses.php has some JavaScript and jQuery in its header that should execute when the submit button is clicked. e.g. below:

```
var urldata = 'r='+rno+'&d='+desc+'&a='+amt+'&e='+exp_type+'&p='+paymode+'&c='+ch_no+'&save=1';
            //alert(urldata);
            
            $.ajax({
                type : "GET",
                data : urldata,
                url:"save.php",
                cache: false,
                success:function(result2){
                    $(".div1").html(result2);
                } // ends success function
            }); // ends ajax call
```

but after the part of the html has been loaded into the page,  the submit button will not work.

Kindly suggest the correct way.

Comment: @user1862764 not fully understanding your question, are you trying to bind an onclick listener to the SUBMIT button which is loaded using AJAX? Is that your requirement?

Comment: What is the JavaScript you need to run after AJAX is complete? There are a few approaches, and some are better than others depending on what code you want to run.

Comment: If you want to run an external JavaScript file once, use [`.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/). If you need to run the code at other times as well, wrap it in a function and call that. It may or may not be necessary to delegate event handlers depending on whether you have any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `#save_expenses` is loaded asynchronously, I believe that you want to delegate the event that you are binding.  For example, you may have:

```
$("#save_expenses").on('click' ...
```

However, since `#save_expenses` doesn't exist when this is bound, you need to delegate it:

```
$("#code_block").on('click', '#save_expenses', function () { ...
```

Comment: Yep, i think this is what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 0):

you may add javascript within your HTML, it will get executed:

```html
<table id="">
  <tr>
    <td><span class="f3">Cheque No</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="ch_no" id="ch_no" value=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="save_expenses" id="save_expenses" value="Save Expenses">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $('#save_expenses').click(function(){
    var urldata = 'r='+rno+'&d='+desc+'&a='+amt+'&e='+exp_type+'&p='+paymode+'&c='+ch_no+'&save=1';
        //alert(urldata);

        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            data : urldata,
            url:"save.php",
            cache: false,
            success:function(result2){
                $(".div1").html(result2);
            } // ends success function
        }); // ends ajax call
    });
 </script> <!-- OR --> <script src="yourfile.js"></script>
```

or you should use event delegation (that's the right way to do it), so it doesn't matter when the code was loaded:

```js
$(document).on('submit', '#save_expenses', function(){
  // will work forever
  var urldata = 'r='+rno+'&d='+desc+'&a='+amt+'&e='+exp_type+'&p='+paymode+'&c='+ch_no+'&save=1';
        //alert(urldata);

        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            data : urldata,
            url:"save.php",
            cache: false,
            success:function(result2){
                $(".div1").html(result2);
            } // ends success function
        }); // ends ajax call
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your quick replies
I could not post all my codes here for you to see..

What i was trying to do was to create a dynamic select menu that auto populate the options stored in a database table. that was why i was trying to use the load to reload the page so that it includes the menus.

Step 1[image: image 1]

step 2[image: image 2]

Step 3 [image: image 3]

I thank you all for your effort.
im grateful